# PyQt: Setting pushbutton color on Big Sur

Tags: pyqt, macos-big-sur, qtwidgets

On Ubuntu 18.04, the following code produces a simple pushbutton with a green background and red text; On Big Sur the background remains unchanged - any thoughts?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg

app = qtw.QApplication([])

button = qtw.QPushButton('Pushbutton')
palette = button.palette()
palette.setColor(qtg.QPalette.Button, qtg.QColor('green'))
palette.setColor(qtg.QPalette.ButtonText, qtg.QColor('red'))
button.setPalette(palette)
button.show()

app.exec()
```

[image: Result on Big Sur]
[image: Result on Ubuntu 18.04]

Comment: Styles do not always follow the palette, and this is valid especially for Windows and MacOS, as explained in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#details): "**Warning:** Some styles do not use the palette for all drawing, for instance, if they make use of native theme engines. This is the case for both the Windows Vista and the macOS styles.". If you want to be sure that the button uses your colors, you need to use stylesheets. Try with a basic `button.setStyleSheet('background: green; color: red;');`, but remember that if you want to set the style sheet for the parent ->

Comment: -> or the application, you should not use generic properties like that, but use [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types), like: `app.setStyleSheet('QPushButton { background: green; color: red; }')`. If you use generic properties on parents you'll risk unexpected behavior for complex widgets, like QComboBox or QScrollBar (including scroll bars for scroll areas).